# What package has this python function?

Tags: python, numpy, mayavi

I found this code in web but it doesn't work.

```
from numpy import *
from mayavi import *

N = 100 
a = 0.
b = 1.
dt = b / N;

q = [1., -1., 1., -1.]
qpos = [[0.56, 0.56, 0.50],
        [0.26, 0.76, 0.50],
        [0.66, 0.16, 0.50],
        [0.66, 0.86, 0.50]]

x,y,z = mgrid[a:b:dt, a:b:dt, 0.:1.:0.5]
Ex, Ey, Ez = mgrid[a:b:dt, a:b:dt, 0.:1.:0.5]

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        Ex[i,j] = 0.0
        Ey[i,j] = 0.0
        for num in range(len(q)):
            rs = ((x[i,j] - qpos[num][0])**2 + (y[i,j] - qpos[num][1])**2)
            r = sqrt(rs)
            q1x = q[num] * (x[i,j] - qpos[num][0]) / (r * rs)
            q1y = q[num] * (y[i,j] - qpos[num][1]) / (r * rs)
            Ex[i,j] = q1x + Ex[i,j]
            Ey[i,j] = q1y + Ey[i,j]

fig = figure(fgcolor=(0,0,0), bgcolor=(1,1,1))
streams = list()

for s in range(len(q)):
    stream = flow(x,y,z,Ex, Ey, Ez, seed_scale=0.5, seed_resolution=1, seedtype='sphere')
    streams.append(stream)

fig.scene.z_plus_view()
fig.scene.parallel_projection = True
```

I have installed numpy and mayavi but when I try to run. doesn't recognize figure and flow function. do I need some other library?

Comment: You picked up some stray code somewhere and you want us to fix it when you aren't even sure what it does?

Comment: I don't think that's the code you found in the web.

Comment: That `import *` usage makes it harder to tell which is the source of the various functions.

Answer (score 1):

First, check out that you have NumPy and Mayavi actually working. Just run `python` (or IDLE) and when you see the `>>>` prompt type `import numpy` and then `import mayavi`. If you see any `ImportError` messages (or any other errors), then you don't. Normally, all you should have is another `>>>` prompt.

Here's how it should look like:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import mayavi
>>>
```

If you have it working, a wild guess is you can try adding this right below the `import` statements:

```
from mayavi.mlab import flow
from mayavi.tools.figure import figure
```

And maybe it would work.

(I'm not actually familiar with Mayavi library and don't know what your code does — just found the suspect functions on Google.)